# Delay in loading angular app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I currently have an Asp.net mvc app and within i have an angular2 app. I am experiencing some delay when i run my application overall - my angular app loads on the page after 4 seconds. I don't know why the page waits 4 seconds to load my angular2 landing page. I know that AOT and lazy loading are to be considered but i would like to know is there a way in structuring or loading/rendering my angular2 within my asp.net app.

I would like to know what to consider to minimize the loading page to 1 second. Whether the structure of my app.module needs to be in a specific way. Would really appreciate any help or guidance on this topic.

Comment: Use the browsers dev tools to investigate. There a mio possibilities what could cause the delay. Listing them in an answer probably won't help you much.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer I totally understand what you are saying i am just thinking could the info i have in my app.component or app.module could case a delay or is the delay from the asp.net mvc side. When looking in the dev tools in google i see certain js files rendered but after 4 seconds my angular component loads.

Comment: Add at least the timeline you get in devtools to your question. Currently there is no information that would allow to make any conclusions.